# Can Visual Studio 2012 Premium (with Blend) be used for commercial purpose?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I know I know that there is a link which explain Visual Studio editions https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/  this link explains only 2019 edition of community, enterprise and professional but I do not find enough information about **Visual Studio 2012 Premium(with Blend)** edition and I want to know if can it be used for commercial purposes for free and what are the restrictions and limitations of using it in commercial?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: YES (By IANAL applies!)

Professional & Premium edition (and Enterprise/Ultimate) have always been usable for any commercial purpose. It is only Community editions that have specific limits (because free).

Comment: @DemGergo oops, wrote pro when I meant premium: all paid editions are (AFAICR) always "unlimited"

Comment: What If I got Premium version for free(got it on a DVD for example) and make product for sale as an  individual with VS, will I be penalized if yes how or how much can be a penalty?

Comment: @DemGergo AFAIUI a valid licence is a valid licence (the media is not the significant issue here).